# How to achieve partially color changing of drawable?

Tags: android, drawable, material-components-android

I am changing my app's design infrastructure to Material Design Components and would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is from [toggle button](https://material.io/components/buttons#theming) and it shows that a drawable can be colored partially, but there is no implementation example how to achieve this. In my app I have a text formatting toolbar with foreground color and I need to get shown the selected text color exactly in that way.

Comment: I think that this is either a complex component (that is, it internally consists of other components, so that they can have multiple colors), or custom View, which draws on canvas directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split icon into 2 parts (same sized), for example we can take "format color text" icon from [material icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons)

[image: 2]

and then simple combine two drawables into one using `<layer-list>` (`LayerDrawable`)

ic_format_color_text.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_format_color_text_black_part1_24dp" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_format_color_text_black_part2_24dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Now, this drawable can be used as an icon for your button (`MaterialButtonToggleGroup` + `MaterialButton`). To tint "bottom shape" part only:

```
val dr = (colorTextBtn.icon as? LayerDrawable)?.getDrawable(0 /* colored shape layer index*/)
dr?.let { DrawableCompat.setTint(dr, /* color */) }
```

[image]